# How to design a persistent object where a generic type would be greatly helpful

Tags: c#, .net, generics, orm

I'm creating an object that will be used to store 'known quantities' or facts. Ideally, it'd look something like:

```
public class KnownQuantity<T> 
{
    public T Quantity { get; set; }

    public KnownQuantity(T quantity)
    {
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }
}
```

However, this class is to become a persistent object. Currently I'm using DevExpress XPO, but the ORM isn't set in stone if another one will support this kind of usage.

How would I go about something like this?

Answer (score 0):

[DataObjects.Net](http://dataobjectsdotnet.googlecode.com/hg/Manual/index.htm) supports automatic registration (~= automatic mapping) of generic instances in cases like this, if you'd set a constraint for T.

See an [example model with open generics for it](http://code.google.com/p/dataobjectsdotnet/source/browse/Xtensive.Storage/Xtensive.Storage.Tests/Issues/Issue0597_OpenGenericsInDomainModel.cs#55).